# x11vnc with virtual display causes window trail

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display, intel-graphics, vnc

I'm using x11vnc on my ubuntu 20.04 to connect my tablet to my virtual display, which I created with xrandr as follows:

```
xrandr --newmode "2000x1200_60.00"  201.50  2000 2136 2352 2704  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync 
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2000x1200_60.00 
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2000x1200_60.00 --below eDP-1 
adb reverse tcp:5900 tcp:5900 
x11vnc -clip 2000x1200+0+1080 -viewonly
```

However, the windows are not rendered properly and I end up getting window trails as shown below:
[image: Window trail in vnc client]

I also cannot maximize the windows. According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357959/vnc-server-as-a-virtual-x11-monitor-to-expand-screen-problem/391574#391574) it seems that I need to create virtual displays instead of using HDMI output.
I did try creating a `xorg.conf` file with dummy driver and also with the intel driver, but I either get glitches or the screen gets black after I reboot.
Most solutions in this forum seem to be outdated. Is there a safer way to create virtual displays? I have this intel graphics card: `Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620`.

**Also:** is there a way to use vnc and virtual desktops with Wayland?
Using `x11vnc -rawfb console` shows a black screen on my vnc client. Is it even possible to mirror the desktop in Wayland?

Comment: You could try searching for a bug similar to this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openbox/+bug/1862756 My hunch is a grub setting could fix the problem but I haven't experienced it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find anything.

Comment: It's a glitch in the Matrix ;-) - Why are you using `adb reverse tcp:5900 tcp:5900`?

Comment: I'm connecting my tablet over adb because it renders faster, but the same issue happens when I connect over wifi.